# Cache MP3's in HTML5 for listening offline?

Tags: javascript, html, download, local-storage, fileapi

I have written an web app that can be used on any device. Because of this, many users use their mobile devices to stream music. Since many people have lost their unlimited plans, I would like to offer a way to "pre download the files" to then be streamed locally instead of from the server?

Is this at all possible using HTML5 LocalStorage?
If so, is anyone out there doing it?
And where is their documentation on how this could be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: not with localStorage. look into indexedDB, webSQL, and input type=file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using localSorage you can only store key-value pairs and value can be only a string. Try to use

### [HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

I am not sure if you can File API on mobile devices too. I think to read/write files in mobile, you need to write some Mobile OS specific native code.

Comment: The File system and File writer APIs (which is needed for this) is only supported in [Chrome](http://caniuse.com/filesystem) and the API is not quite "set in stone". But Indexed DB/Web SQL can be used as fallbacks.